# How to use packages in Plain TeX?

Tags: packages, tex-core, plain-tex

How to use packages in Plain TeX? Are there any packages for Plain TeX at all or are packages a feature  only for LaTeX?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A LaTeX package is a roughly a collection of macro definitions that extend or modify the standard features.

There are several extensions of plain TeX around:

```
> ls /usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/plain

amsfonts/       etex/           hyplain/        makeindex/      present/
antt/           figflow/        ifetex/         metatex/        resumemac/
armenian/       fixpdfmag/      iwona/          mkpattern/      rsfs/
asapsym/        font-change/    js-misc/        newsletr/       semaphor/
base/           fontch/         knitting/       omega/          standalone/
config/         fp/             knuth-lib/      pgf/            timetable/
cweb/           getoptk/        knuth-local/    pgfplots/       treetex/
cyrplain/       gfnotation/     kotex-plain/    pitex/          tugboat-plain/
encxvlna/       graphics-pln/   kurier/         placeins-plain/ varisize/
enigma/         gustlib/        lambda-lists/   plipsum/        velthuis/
epsf-dvipdfmx/  hanoi/          lh/             plnfss/         vntex/
esint-type1/    harvmac/        ly1/            plstmary/       wasy/
```

and you find also many “generic packages” with

```
> ls /usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic
```

A notable set of macros is `amstex`, which lives in its own tree

```
> ls /usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/amstex
```

and you find others (in particular `opmac`) in

```
> ls /usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/csplain
```

and `eplain` lives in

```
> ls /usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/eplain
```

Use the similar paths for MiKTeX if you happen to use that distribution.

Comment: Perhaps also worth noting that plain TeX searches the LaTeX tree, so can find for example `graphics.tex` or `expl3-generic.tex`.

Comment: I think OP was also asking how to use them in practice --- does `\usepackage` work also in plain Tex? If not, what is the correct syntax?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni `\input` is the plain tex (tex primitive) syntax.